# Linking nghttp2 static library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, nghttp2

I want to compile a simple server app using [nghtt2_asio](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/libnghttp2_asio.html) in C++.

It compiles perfectly under shared libraries:

`g++ server.cpp -O2 -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -lnghttp2_asio -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -o server`

But as I compile it statically:

`g++ server.cpp -static -O2 -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -o server -lssl -ldl -pthread -lcrypto -ldl -pthread -lnghttp2_asio -lboost_system`

the linker gives me these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): in function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x14): attenzione: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o): in function `BIO_lookup_ex':
(.text+0xd0b): attenzione: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o): in function `BIO_gethostbyname':
(.text+0x72): attenzione: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_common.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::nghttp2_category_impl::message[abi:cxx11](int) const':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_common.cc:40: undefined reference to `nghttp2_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server.o): in function `int nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::on_read<8192ul>(boost::array<unsigned char, 8192ul> const&, unsigned long)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.h:103: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_mem_recv'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server.o): in function `boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::engine(ssl_ctx_st*)':
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp:55: undefined reference to `BIO_new_bio_pair'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server.o): in function `int nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::on_write<65536ul>(boost::array<unsigned char, 65536ul>&, unsigned long&)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.h:129: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_mem_send'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server.o): in function `int nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::on_read<8192ul>(boost::array<unsigned char, 8192ul> const&, unsigned long)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.h:103: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_mem_recv'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server.o): in function `int nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::on_write<65536ul>(boost::array<unsigned char, 65536ul>&, unsigned long&)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.h:129: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_mem_send'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server.o): in function `int nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::on_read<8192ul>(boost::array<unsigned char, 8192ul> const&, unsigned long)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.h:103: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_mem_recv'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::(anonymous namespace)::on_frame_not_send_callback(nghttp2_session*, nghttp2_frame const*, int, void*)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:230: undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_rst_stream'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::~http2_handler()':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:258: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_del'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::start()':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:274: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `std::_Bind<void (*(nghttp2_session_callbacks*))(nghttp2_session_callbacks*)>::_Bind(std::_Bind<void (*(nghttp2_session_callbacks*))(nghttp2_session_callbacks*)>&&)':
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/functional:494: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_del'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::start()':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:281: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_begin_headers_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:283: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_header_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:285: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_recv_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:287: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_data_chunk_recv_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:289: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_stream_close_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:291: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_send_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:293: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_not_send_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:296: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_server_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:302: undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_settings'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::should_stop() const':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:333: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_want_read'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:334: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_want_write'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::stream_error(int, unsigned int)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:47: undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_rst_stream'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::resume(nghttp2::asio_http2::server::stream&)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:428: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_resume_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::(anonymous namespace)::on_header_callback(nghttp2_session*, nghttp2_frame const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char, void*)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:109: undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_rst_stream'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::submit_trailer(nghttp2::asio_http2::server::stream&, std::multimap<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value> > >)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:387: undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_trailer'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::start_response(nghttp2::asio_http2::server::stream&)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:366: undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_response'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-asio_server_http2_handler.o): in function `nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2_handler::push_promise(boost::system::error_code&, nghttp2::asio_http2::server::stream&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::multimap<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value> > >)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/asio_server_http2_handler.cc:454: undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_push_promise'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-http2.o): in function `nghttp2::http2::determine_window_update_transmission(nghttp2_session*, int)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/http2.cc:577: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_get_effective_recv_data_length'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/http2.cc:578: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_get_effective_local_window_size'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/http2.cc:580: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_get_stream_effective_recv_data_length'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/http2.cc:582: undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_get_stream_effective_local_window_size'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a(libnghttp2_asio_la-http2.o): in function `nghttp2::http2::check_nv(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
/home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/http2.cc:698: undefined reference to `nghttp2_check_header_name'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Downloads/nghttp2/src/http2.cc:701: undefined reference to `nghttp2_check_header_value'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone explain me what happens?

Comment: In Linux most of libs are shared libs, which depend on other also shared libs. If you compile statically then you need all libs to be static, including those used by other libs. Bottom line: Don't do this. Linux is not Windows ;)

Comment: First line of the manual: libnghttp2_asio is C++ library **built on top of libnghttp2**. Where is libnghttp2 in your build script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain me what happens?

There are several problems here.

1. You have unresolved symbols. As n.m. said in a comment, you need to add `-libnghttp2`.
2. Your order of libraries on the link line is wrong. Lower-level libraries should *follow* higher-level libraries on the link line. The right order is something like:

```
-lnghttp2_asio -libnghttp2 -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
```

See [this blog](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) post for explanation.

3. You are linking a fully-static binary.

Contrary to popular belief, such binaries (at least on Linux) are *significantly* less portable than dynamically linked ones.

What the warning is telling you is that *IF* you try to run this binary on a system that has a different version of GLIBC installed (could be a different system from the one you built on, or even the *same* system but after an upgrade to a different version of GLIBC), then your binary may crash (and very likely will crash).

You will be *much* better off not doing a fully-static link.

Note: you don't have to link against `libnghttp2_asio` etc. dynamically, just against the `libc` and `libdl` and `libcrypto`.